# Tags class with comma separated values or separated tables?

Tags: php, sql, join, csv, tags

I need to add a tags system to one of my websites.

Right now i am coding something lke this:

tags_table

```
CREATE TABLE `tags_table` (
`id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`seo_url` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

files_table have "tags" field [varchar(250)]

When i add new tags:

- i list all tags from tags_table and select the ones i want
- i save the tag names to files_table.tags -> comma separated values

That way is easier to show the file tags.

When i edit the file:
- select/unselect the tags and save again.

Method II with different tables:

- i know that i can make separated table like tags_files and put tag_id and file_id

But when i edit the file how i check what tags were added or removed for that file?

What is more efficient?

Comma separated values in a field or different tables?

Also, when i edit a tag name or delete a tag the changes should be made on all files too.

Comment: Do not use comma seperated column. Thats defeats the purpose of relational database. Go for different table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use comma separated values. They tend to be slower to query. The one exception might be if you use FULLTEXT indexes and MATCH using MySQL, but then you tie yourself to a specific DBMS *and* a specific storage engine (MyISAM).

If you have a separate table with tags and a link table that links tag ids to files, you have these advantages:

- Deleting a tag is as simple as deleting all records with that id from the link table and then deleting the tag record.
- Renaming the tag is just a single update.
- You can easily query the list of available tags and do a fast count to see how often it it used.
- Referential integrity (foreign keys) that prevent you from deleting a tag that is still in use.
- Faster queries than using 'LIKE' or something to find files that match a tag.
- and probably much more.

Comment: my issue is when i edit the file ... i can't see how i can check what tags i removed and what tags were added. I mean i get the list of tag ids from tags_files for that file, then i remove 2 tags and and 3 new tags, how i will delete the removed tags? if i remove them no id will be passed

Comment: That has more to do with the implementation of the interface. You'll have to remember the names or ids of the tags you remove, so you can also delete them from the database.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements you need:

1. Changes to be made on all files
2. Efficiency

I would highly suggest using a separate table for storing `tags_files` as then you can simply add or remove a tag from the file but deleting or adding a new entry in the `tags_files` table.

The comma separated approach is not good for the following reason:

1. For each change you will be editing the row in the files tag.
2. Searching will be tougher as you will not be able to take advantage is MySQL search functions and you will be forced to use string search which might not be that efficient.